# How to create a organic-group-alias/content-type subpage?

Tags: views, organic-groups, path-aliases

I've created a page via views that show a list of all the nodes of a specific content type in a specific group.

`/node/groupid/post` lists all the nodes of type post in groupid.

But what I really need, is to be able to use the groups path alias. So:

`/group-name-here/post` should work for `/node/groupid/post`.

How can I do that?

#### site specs

Drupal 7.41

Views 3.11

OG 2.7

Pathauto 1.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Views treats aliases the same as `node/id`. So, in the view, just set the path to `node/id/post` or similar.